# jQuery request submitting twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, double-submit-problem

```
$("#classesLink").click(function(event) {
    $("#globalUserContent").children().slideUp("normal", function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "classes.php?token="+randString+"",
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#globalUserContent").html(msg);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                $("#globalUserContent").html(msg);
            }
        });            
    });
    return false;
});
```

I have the above code and when i click the `.classesLink` button and check the firebug requests, it shows that it is being submitted twice, is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: Check the type of the button. If it is <input type="button" ..> or just <button>. In IE, just <button> acts will default to an submit button based on the current document compatibility mode..

Comment: its actually a link, not a button

Comment: The code here look ok, at least I think. However, we need to see more.  Maybe this `.click` is inside a `function` which is called twice. Remember that `click` handler is not overwritten but added to handlers' list....

Comment: Fyi, in case `randString` is just a cache buster, you can use `cache: false` and let jQuery add one.

Comment: Perhaps you have multiple #globalUserContent or multiple children of it? Otherwise try restarting the browser and try other browsers.

Comment: try by removing the children().slideUp code..I mean see how AJAX works when you put the code directly under click event. What if the globalUserContent has more than one children? WOuld AJAX code run for each child? I may not be true.

Comment: Could add `console.log(event.currentTarget);`  in the event handler function (just bellow `.click` line). and report back what you see in Console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by @am not I am. `$("#globalUserContent")` has two childrens so the callback fires twice one for each child, use this:

```
$("#classesLink").click(function(event) {
    $.when($("#globalUserContent").children().slideUp("normal"))
     .then(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "classes.php?token="+randString+"",
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#globalUserContent").html(msg);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                $("#globalUserContent").html(msg);
            }
        });            
    });
    return false;
});
```

This will execute the callback- ajax requst, when the `slideUp` effect is finished, And doesn't hardcode the `setTimeout` delay in the code.

If you hardcode `600` in the code, the code could break if the `"normal"` duration will change some day, or someone changed the `slideUp` duration effect but didn't change the timeout delay.

But you can put the duration-delay in a variable so you change it in one place - @am not I am suggestion.

`when` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/):

> Description: Provides a way to execute callback functions based on one or more objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.

Comment: @Grigor. Actually, am not I am  Is the master, but this is better as it doesn't hardcode the `setTimeout`

Comment: wait so I can't give that person a tick?

Comment: @Grigor. What did you mean in the last comment?

Answer (score 5):

This...

```
$("#globalUserContent").children()
```

...is probably matching 2 elements, so the handler fires twice.

---

You can use a `setTimeout` instead.

```
$("#globalUserContent").children().slideUp("normal");

setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "classes.php?token="+randString+"",
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#globalUserContent").html(msg);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                $("#globalUserContent").html(msg);
            }
        });
}, 600);
```

Comment: Even better, use `when` + `then`

Comment: @gdoron: I've never bothered with deferreds. Sounds like a good alternative.

Comment: @Shiplu: I just prefer it that way.

Comment: If you hardcode `600` in the code, the code could break if the `"normal"` duration will change some day, or someone changed the slideUp duration effect but didn't change the timeout delay.

Comment: Oh, I thought you did it by mistake. :)

Comment: @gdoron: True. If they need to be synchronized, I'd put it in a variable so you change it in one place. I just prefer lower-level code a little more.